# Compiling C++ Code With Boost's regex_match

Tags: c++, regex, string, boost, matching

Given this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;


int main  ( int arg_count, char *arg_vec[] ) {
    if (arg_count !=2 ) {
        cerr << "expected one argument" << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    string InputString = arg_vec[1];
    string toMatch = "FOO";

    const regex e(toMatch);
    if (const regex_match(InputString, e)) {// this is line 26
        cout << "Match" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "No Match" << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with this command:

```
g++ -I /home/foolishbrat/.boost/include/boost-1_37 test.cc -o test
```

It gives this error:

```
test.cc: In function `int main(int, char**)':
test.cc:26: error: syntax error before `)' token
```

What's wrong with my code?

If I remove "const" in line 26 and compiled with the same command. 
I will get this errors:

```
/misc/raid2/Melchior/foolishbrat/tmp/ccr3zzcH.o(.gnu.linkonce.t._ZN5boost11regex_matchIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS5_EEEcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEbT_SD_RNS_13match_resultsISD_T0_EERKNS_11basic_regexIT1_T2_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsE+0x61): In function `bool boost::regex_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >&, boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)':
: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::match()'
/misc/raid2/Melchior/foolishbrat/tmp/ccr3zzcH.o(.gnu.linkonce.t._ZN5boost11basic_regexIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE6assignEPKcS7_j+0x27): In function `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned)':
: undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned)'
/misc/raid2/Melchior/foolishbrat/tmp/ccr3zzcH.o(.gnu.linkonce.t._ZN5boost9re_detail12perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEC1ES6_S6_RNS_13match_resultsIS6_S9_EERKNS_11basic_regexIcSD_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsES6_+0xf2): In function `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::perl_matcher[in-charge](__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >&, boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >)':
: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Update:**

Resolved with this compilation and linking:

```
g++ -I ~/.boost/include/boost-1_37 test.cc -o test  /home/foolishbrat/.boost/lib/libboost_regex-gcc33-mt-1_37.a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link the necessary boost libraries.
Add `-l <path to libraries>` to the build command

Answer (score 1):

```
if (const regex_match(InputString, e)) {// this is line 26
```

You don't need to (and indeed, should not) say `const` here. Just remove the word, and at least this error should go away.

Comment: Typically, the sheer number of compiler/linker errors is not an indication of your progress. You may fix one issue, and get many more errors than previously, because the compilation can now proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `const` keyword on line 26.